# DevExpress ASPxGridView asp.net Grid doesn't show data after Enabling ScrollBars

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm new user for AspxGridView for DevExpress ...
Please if someone's using ASPxGridView, describe me why after enabling scroll bar the grid hides all data even columns headers and rows.
I can't make the width stay as the value I put except enabling the scroll bar, 
But the data is keeping hide it self, what's wrong?

Comment: Khaleel, I recommend you contact the DevExpress support team as there is not enough info here that you described to help you: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Devexpress`

> you can display the vertical scrollbar by using the
>   Settings.ShowVerticalScrollBar property, and specify the height of the
>   scrollable area (in pixels) via the Settings.VerticalScrollableHeight
>   property. By default, the grid's width depends on the number of
>   visible columns. If there are too many columns within the grid, you
>   can enable horizontal scrolling via the
>   Settings.ShowHorizontalScrollBar property and define the desired
>   scrollable area width by using the grid's Width property.

Have your tried like [`Data Paging and Scrolling - Scrolling`](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/Scrolling.aspx)

They run like this in .cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for(int i = 7; i < Grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            Grid.Columns[i].Visible = chkHorizontal.Checked;
```

Comment: Thank you Soner Gönül thats exactly what I need